# Overlay divs over image, not knowing height of image/container div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap v4.
I have an image, I want it stretched (keeping its aspect ratio) to the full width of the page, will means the image/image container's height can change.
I also want a div on the top and bottom of the image.

Bootstrap [has](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) `row align-items-start` and `row align-items-end` which I used to try to make my divs go where I want, but it didn't seem to work.

I'm not sure if it is possible to overlay elements like how I want, due to the image/container div resizes. Possibly I need to use javascript for this.

HTML

```
<div class="outer container-fluid">
    <img id="cats" class="img-fluid" src="http://placekitten.com/g/800/100">

    <div class="myboxes container-fluid">

        <div class="row align-items-start">
            <div class="col-1 redbox">Top</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-end">
            <div class="col-1 bluebox">Bottom</div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
}
.redbox {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
    height: 20px;
}
.bluebox {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
    height: 20px;
}
.myboxes {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
#cats {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
```

[Not working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/5303/)

[Image of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM0lB.png)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.outer {
    position: relative;
}
.redbox {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
    height: 20px;
}
.bluebox {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
    height: 20px;
}
#topBox, #bottomBox { 
  position:absolute;
  left:0
}
.img-fluid {
  width:100%;
  display: block;
}
#topBox {
  top:0
}
#bottomBox {
  bottom:0
}
```

```html
<div class="outer container-fluid">
    <img id="cats" class="img-fluid" src="http://placekitten.com/g/800/100" />
    <div id="topBox" class="row align-items-start">
        <div class="col-1 redbox">Top</div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomBox" class="row align-items-end">
        <div class="col-1 bluebox">Bottom</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was aiming to use the bootstrap class 'align-items-start' but yes, this way works great too.

One problem, the image does not fit the page width if it is smaller than the image, I want the image always 100% of the page width.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  padding:0px;
}

.img-fluid {
  width:100%;
}

.box {
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  height: 20px;
}

.top {
  top:0px;
  background: red;
}

.bottom {
  bottom:5px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box top">TOP</div>
  <div class="box bottom">BOTTOM</div>
  <img id="cats" class="img-fluid" src="http://placekitten.com/g/800/100"/>
</div>
```

It's very much possible to overlay element like you want to and fairly easy too. You don't even need so many classes and div's for doing so.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using bootstrap and trying to make use of the grid layout, that's why I was using rows and columns.

One problem, the image does not fit the page width if it is smaller than the image, I want the image always 100% of the page width. The image grows if the page is very wide, but does not shrink if very narrow.

Comment: Image is shrinking for me. Try to add class "img-fluid" in your css with width = 100%. If still its now working then can you send some screenshot how it is right now and how it should be?